# How to delete lines that touch polygon boundaries

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

I have a polygon layer with a polygon and a line layer. I need only middle line and I tried to delete lines that touch polygon boundaries. For it I used Select but location tool but it didn't work. Either all lines are selected or nothing. I tried all variants. And I also make my line the simplest. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]

I need only green lines (the middle path):
[image]

Update:
You methods work well for the polygon I described higher. But for some reason it doesn’t work for a very complex polygon. For manual case, it selects only part of the lines. For expression it selects all lines. Do you know why?
The second polygon
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have loaded my second polygon in here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fDNG_4QGPywVKGvY_QyfpwgKoK29i_NO?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 7):

You can extract the polygon boundary (`boundary` tool), then select lines that intersect the boundary layer. At last, you can invert the selection so only the lines not touching the polygon boundary get selected.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my post. Please, check it.

Comment: You can use the tool `select within distance` instead of `select by location` and use a size of 0.001 (or whatever works)

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

[@JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh)'s workflow using the *Extract by expression* tool

```sql
not   -- invert the selection
intersects(
    $geometry,
    buffer(
        -- collect the polygon into a multipart geometry and get its boundary
        boundary(     
            aggregate('poly', 'collect', $geometry)
        ), 
        1    -- small buffer distance
    )
)
```

A small buffer is applied to the boundary because, in my case, after clipping and exploding, some of the line ends no longer intersect the boundary.

###### Result

The red line layer is the result of the expression.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my post. Please, check it.

Comment: Can you provide a download link to some sample data? I will take a look why it is not behaving as expected.

Comment: Yes https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fDNG_4QGPywVKGvY_QyfpwgKoK29i_NO

Comment: I think may be it because polygon size. It it so small

Comment: You will probably need to adjust the buffer size. I used 1 m in my example, but my polygon was about 50 km wide.

Comment: I had a look at your data. A buffer size of 0.001 works.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: could you help me one more time? I tried to use your geometry expression on very complicated layer with several polygons. And I have error 0 is not a geometry. I've described it here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475344/error-0-is-not-a-geometry  May be you can find out what's happened. With a simple polygon it worked extremely good, but not here