# Error "0 is not a geometry"

Tags: qgis, error

I created Voronoi polygons for my polygon, then I converted them to lines and exploded the lines. Then I tried to select the polygon skeleton as described here (it has worked earlier on another simple polygon [How to delete lines that touch polygon boundaries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474683/how-to-delete-lines-that-touch-polygon-boundaries/474686#474686) by using geometry expression), but I get an error "0 is not a geometry".
What does it mean? Perhaps the lines exploded unsuccessfully? Or is there a problem with the coordinate system?
I checked geometry but I don't have invalid objects.
[image]

It also gave nothing
[image]

May be it because I have several polygons that I divided into Voronoy sectors?
[image]

Comment: What if you check for <$geometry=0> ?

Comment: Yes, it also got nothing

Comment: I loaded my layers here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R4D6IGWdG01PRDkC6C2Lx21jvsjia0l8?usp=drive_link

Comment: And used expression

Comment: not   
intersects(
    $geometry,
    buffer(
        boundary(     
            aggregate('1 polygon', 'collect', $geometry)
        ), 
        1    
    )
)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used a wrong tool for it. I need Select by expression, not Geometry by expression